# How to monkeypatch builtin function datetime.datetime.now?

Tags: python, unit-testing, datetime, monkeypatching, pytest

I'd like to make sure that `datetime.datetime.now()` returns a specific datetime for testing purposes, How do I do this? I've tried with pytest's monkeypatch

```
monkeypatch.setattr(datetime.datetime,"now", nowfunc)
```

But this gives me the error `TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'datetime.datetime'`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the error tells you, you can't monkeypatch the attributes of many extension types implemented in C. (Other Python implementations may have different rules than CPython, but they often have similar restrictions.)

The way around this is to create a subclass, and monkeypatch the *class*.

For example (untested, because I don't have `pytest` handy… but it works with manual monkeypatching):

```
class patched_datetime(datetime.datetime): pass
monkeypatch.setattr(patched_datetime, "now", nowfunc)
datetime.datetime = patched_datetime
```

Comment: That's a good start, but then you also need to make sure that `nowfunc` is bound correctly. Here's a nice complete solution for py.test: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503373/how-to-monkeypatch-pythons-datetime-datetime-now-with-py-test

Answer (score 1):

You can't, as the error shows. If you need to do this, you'll need to change the  code under test so that it has a utility function that calls `datetime.datetime.now()`, and change all the references to point to that function instead. Then, you can monkeypatch that function to return a time of your choice.