# How to monkeypatch python's datetime.datetime.now with py.test?

Tags: python, datetime, mocking, pytest

I need to test functions which uses `datetime.datetime.now()`. What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You need to monkeypatch datetime.now function. In example below, I'm creating fixture which I can re-use later in other tests:

```
import datetime
import pytest

FAKE_TIME = datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 25, 17, 5, 55)

@pytest.fixture
def patch_datetime_now(monkeypatch):

    class mydatetime(datetime.datetime):
        @classmethod
        def now(cls):
            return FAKE_TIME

    monkeypatch.setattr(datetime, 'datetime', mydatetime)


def test_patch_datetime(patch_datetime_now):
    assert datetime.datetime.now() == FAKE_TIME
```

Comment: Is it possible to only replace the `now` method?

Comment: This works, but not if you do "from datetime import datetime". Take a look here for detais: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35431476/why-pythons-monkeypatch-doesnt-work-when-importing-a-class-instead-of-a-module

Comment: I was able to adjust this answer and patch `utcnow`

Comment: Your `mydatetime` class should subclass `datetime.datetime`, otherwise it won't be able to perform any of the other methods datetime.datetime normally performs.

Comment: @mareoraft That might not be enough.  I tried that, and it works well enough in the MCVE, but in my real environment a pandas import failed with `TypeError: type 'pandas._libs.tslibs.base.ABCTimestamp' is not dynamically allocated but its base type 'mydatetime' is dynamically allocated`.

Comment: Use `class mydatetime(datetime.datetime):` to avoid problems calling other methods of the class.

Comment: This didn't work for uses of datetime.now in other modules in the code base.

Answer (score 58):

There is [`freezegun` module](http://stevepulec.com/freezegun/):

```
from datetime import datetime
from freezegun import freeze_time # $ pip install freezegun

@freeze_time("Jan 14th, 2012")
def test_nice_datetime():
    assert datetime.now() == datetime(2012, 1, 14)
```

`freeze_time()` could also be used as a context manager. The module support specifying the local timezone UTC offset.

Answer (score 16):

How about using `MagicMock(wrap=datetime.datetime)` ?

This aproach mocks `datetime.datetime.now()` but the other methods are available same with the original `datetime.datetime`.

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

def test_datetime_now(monkeypatch):
    import datetime
    FAKE_NOW = datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 11, 14, 0, 0)
    datetime_mock = MagicMock(wraps=datetime.datetime)
    datetime_mock.now.return_value = FAKE_NOW
    monkeypatch.setattr(datetime, "datetime", datetime_mock)

    assert datetime.datetime.now() == FAKE_NOW

    # the other methods are available
    assert datetime.datetime.fromisoformat("2020-03-01T00:00:00") == datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0)
```

Using `@pytest.fixture` approach is here.

```
import datetime
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

import pytest

FAKE_NOW = datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 11, 14, 0, 0)


@pytest.fixture()
def mock_datetime_now(monkeypatch):
    datetime_mock = MagicMock(wraps=datetime.datetime)
    datetime_mock.now.return_value = FAKE_NOW
    monkeypatch.setattr(datetime, "datetime", datetime_mock)


def test_datetime_now2(mock_datetime_now):
    assert datetime.datetime.now() == FAKE_NOW

    assert datetime.datetime.fromisoformat("2020-03-01T00:00:00") == datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: You forgot to import `MagicMock`. So code as is won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I fixed it.

Comment: This will break code that uses `isinstance(value, datetime.datetime)`, for example, tortoise-orm.

Answer (score 10):

This is the fixture I use for overriding now() but keeping the rest of datetime working (RE: satoru's question).

It is not extensively tested, but it does get around issues where datetime is used in other contexts. For me this was important to keep the Django ORM working with these datetime values (Specifically  `isinstance(Freeze.now(), datetime.datetime) == True`).

```
@pytest.fixture
def freeze(monkeypatch):
    """ Now() manager patches datetime return a fixed, settable, value
        (freezes time)
    """
    import datetime
    original = datetime.datetime

    class FreezeMeta(type):
        def __instancecheck__(self, instance):
            if type(instance) == original or type(instance) == Freeze:
                return True

    class Freeze(datetime.datetime):
        __metaclass__ = FreezeMeta

        @classmethod
        def freeze(cls, val):
            cls.frozen = val

        @classmethod
        def now(cls):
            return cls.frozen

        @classmethod
        def delta(cls, timedelta=None, **kwargs):
            """ Moves time fwd/bwd by the delta"""
            from datetime import timedelta as td
            if not timedelta:
                timedelta = td(**kwargs)
            cls.frozen += timedelta

    monkeypatch.setattr(datetime, 'datetime', Freeze)
    Freeze.freeze(original.now())
    return Freeze
```

Perhaps off topic, but might come in handy to other people arriving at this question. This fixture allows "freezing" time, and then moving it back and forth at will within your tests:

```
def test_timesensitive(freeze):
    freeze.freeze(2015, 1, 1)
    foo.prepare()  # Uses datetime.now() to prepare its state
    freeze.delta(days=2)
    # Does something that takes in consideration that 2 days have passed
    # i.e. datetime.now() returns a date 2 days in the future
    foo.do_something()
    assert foo.result == expected_result_after_2_days
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are a lover of pytest-mock, then mock the `datetime.now` using this.

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

def test_time_now(mocker):
    #patch the the datetime method in your file

    mock_date = mocker.patch("your_package.your_package.datetime")
    FAKE_NOW = datetime(2020, 3, 11, 14, 0, 0, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
    mock_date.now.return_value = FAKE_NOW
    
    from your_package.your_package import time_to_test
    timestamp_method = time_to_test()
    assert timestamp_method == FAKE_NOW
```

Answer (score 3):

it handly to use [unittest.mock.patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) as context manager, wright in test:

```
import datetime
import pytest
from unittest.mock import patch


def test_schedule(schedules_db_client):

    faked_now = datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 14, 0, 0)

    with patch("datetime.datetime") as mock_datetime:
        mock_datetime.now.return_value = faked_now

        assert schedules_db_client.get_current_attendant()
```

Answer (score 2):

Adapted from the other answers:

```
import datetime as dt
from contextlib import contextmanager
from unittest.mock import patch

@contextmanager
def mocked_now(now):
    class MockedDatetime(dt.datetime):
        @classmethod
        def now(cls):
            return now

    with patch("datetime.datetime", MockedDatetime):
        yield
```

Used like:

```
def test_now():
    with mocked_now(dt.datetime(2017, 10, 21)):
        assert dt.datetime.now() == dt.datetime(2017, 10, 21)
```

Comment: Where `patch` came from? Did you miss an import?

Comment: You have also missed to import contextmanager: `from contextlib import contextmanager`

Answer (score 1):

#mymodule.py

```
import datetime
```

#test file

```
@patch('mymodule.datetime')
def test_stomething(datetime_mock):
                                                                                
    frozen_now = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1)
    # I here I mock the now call
    datetime_mock.datetime.now.return_value = frozen_now
    # here I want timedelta to actually call the original function
    datetime_mock.timedelta = datetime.timedelta
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another recipe, using `pytest-mock` with an explicit `MagicMock` to wrap only the `now` method:

```py
from datetime import datetime

from my_module import fn_returning_datetime_now

def test_datetime(mocker):
    NOW = dt.datetime(1999,1,1)
    mock_datetime = mocker.MagicMock(wraps=datetime)
    mock_datetime.now.return_value = NOW
    mocker.patch("my_module.datetime", mock_datetime)
    assert fn_returning_datetime_now == NOW
```

This is just a variation on other answers here, using `mocker.patch` instead of `monkeypatch`.