# Why python's monkeypatch doesn't work when importing a class instead of a module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, pytest, monkeypatching

I was having issues while using the code of the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503373/how-to-monkeypatch-pythons-datetime-datetime-now-with-py-test).

*The code works depending on how I do the import of datetime.* Why is that? Is it possible to mock it so it works both ways?

I am using `Python 3.4`. The following code illustrates the problem:

```
import pytest
from datetime import datetime

mockdate = datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def patch_datetime_now(monkeypatch):
    class mydatetime:
        @classmethod
        def now(cls):
            return mockdate

    monkeypatch.setattr('datetime.datetime', mydatetime)

def test_doesnt_work():
    assert datetime.now() == mockdate

def test_works():
    import datetime
    assert datetime.datetime.now() == mockdate
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Even if you aren't using [`mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) framework you should take a look to [*where to patch*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) chapter. By writing

```
from datetime import datetime
```

You are creating a new reference to `datetime.datetime` in your test module and call it `datetime`. That is the reference that you use in `test_doesnt_work()` test.

By writing

```
monkeypatch.setattr('datetime.datetime', mydatetime)
```

You are patching `datetime`'s absolute reference in `datetime` module: the one used in `test_works()`.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful. So, would you know of any way to make it work with "from datetime import datetime" instead of "import datetime"?

Comment: Sure you should patch `yourmodule.datetime` instead. Take a look to mock framework: you can fine `patch` very useful.

Comment: I have created a new answer with the solution, but I still think it's fair I mark your answer as accepted. Cheers!

Answer (score 24):

@Michele d'Amico's answer explains why it doesn't work. This is how to make it work if you want to use "from datetime import datetime" instead of just "import datetime"

```
monkeypatch.setattr(__name__ + '.datetime', mydatetime)
```