# Mocking datetime yields bug in pyarrow

Tags: python, datetime, pyarrow

For testing, I want to mock `datetime.datetime.now()` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503373/how-to-monkeypatch-pythons-datetime-datetime-now-with-py-test).

The function I am testing is reading a table via pyarrow:

```
import pytest
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import datetime

mockdate = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def patch_datetime_now(monkeypatch):
    class mydatetime:
        @classmethod
        def now(cls):
            return mockdate

    monkeypatch.setattr(datetime, 'datetime', mydatetime)
    
def function_to_test():
    date = datetime.datetime.now()
    some_table = pq.read_table("abc/def")
    return some_table, date
    
def test_function_to_test():
    
    table, date = function_to_test()
    
    assert date == mockdate
```

For some reason, mocking the `now()` function creates this very weird bug in pyarrow:

```
ValueError: datetime.datetime size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 48 from C header, got 32 from PyObject
```

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: You didn't just mock `datetime.now`; you mocked the entire class `datetime` with one that has nothing *but* a class method named `now`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Will post a working solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks chepner for the hint. For future reference, here is a working solution:

```
import pytest
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import datetime

mockdate = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
    
def function_to_test():
    date = datetime.datetime.now()
    some_table = pq.read_table("abc/def")
    return some_table, date
    
def test_function_to_test(mocker):

    mocker.patch(__name__  + '.datetime')
    datetime.datetime.now.return_value = mockdate
    
    table, date = function_to_test()
    
    assert date == mockdate
```