# Monkeypatching built-ins

Tags: python, unit-testing, datetime, monkeypatching

For testing I want to monkeypatch some modules, in particular `os` and `datetime`. I am successful in monkeypatching `os` but not `datetime`:

```
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'datetime.datetime'
```

My setup is:

file_to_test.py

```
import os
import datetime

def os_function():
    return os.path.exists('some_path')

def datetime_function():
    return datetime.datetime.now()
```

test_file.py:

```
import file_to_test
import datetime

mockdate = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)


def test_function_to_test(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(file_to_test.os.path, 'exists', (lambda x: True))
    monkeypatch.setattr(file_to_test.datetime.datetime, 'now', (lambda x: mockdate))
    file_exists = file_to_test.os_function()
    date = file_to_test.datetime_function()

    assert file_exists
    assert date == mockdate
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to monkeypatch python's datetime.datetime.now with py.test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503373/how-to-monkeypatch-pythons-datetime-datetime-now-with-py-test)

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a more fundamental answer why these modules behave so differently

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481954/trying-to-mock-datetime-date-today-but-not-working) is another similar question. The modules behave  differently, because they are implemented in C, so you can't set attributes there the Python way (as shown by the error message).

Comment: I can monkeypatch `datetime` attribute of `file_to_test.datetime` but not `now` attribute of `file_to_test.datetime.datetime`, and the error is `TypeError: cannot set 'now' attribute of immutable type 'datetime.datetime'`. Not sure why it's `TypeError` precisely, but these objects are immutable; some security setting is making them inviolate. The `file_to_test.datetime` reference is just a reference slot in your environment which would normally point to the builtin. So you can modify that to point to your mock but not an attribute on the immutable builtin object itself.