# How to patch datetime.datetime.now() using pytest and pass isinstance

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, pytest, monkeypatching

I'm using pytest to perform testing in a Python project that uses the `datetime.datetime` class, `datetime.datetime.now()` function, and `isinstance(time, datetime.datetime)` check. Where time is a DateTime object and the `now()` function is patched.

The `time` variable is not mocked, however, `isinstance(time, datetime.datetime)` returns false. When printing `type(time)`:

```
<class 'test_Itinerarios.patch_datetime_now.<locals>.mydatetime'>
```

How do I properly use pytest and `__instancecheck__`  to pass the `instance(time, datetime.datetime)` test?

The patch class is defined as:

```
Fake_time = datetime.datetime(2024,3,7,18,00)
real_datetime_class = datetime.datetime

@pytest.fixture
def patch_datetime_now(monkeypatch):
    class mydatetime(datetime.datetime):
        @classmethod
        def __instancecheck__(cls, obj):
            return isinstance(obj, real_datetime_class)
        
        @classmethod
        def now(cls):
            return Fake_time
        
    monkeypatch.setattr(datetime,'datetime',mydatetime)
```

EDIT

This is different from [How to monkeypatch python's datetime.datetime.now with py.test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503373/how-to-monkeypatch-pythons-datetime-datetime-now-with-py-test) as that answer would fail at the `instance(time, datetime.datetime)` test. I need the mocked now() time to past the test. Also, I don't want/can import other libraries for the testing procedures.

Comment: Don't do this. Just use a freezegun plugin, such as [pytest-freezer](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-freezer).

Comment: @wim, could you provide more info on how to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to monkeypatch python's datetime.datetime.now with py.test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503373/how-to-monkeypatch-pythons-datetime-datetime-now-with-py-test)

Comment: @MrBeanBremen. Not, it doesn't as the mocked now() would fail a isinstance(time, datetime.datetime) test.

Comment: Use freezegun https://pypi.org/project/freezegun/